How to change MDCOutlinedTextField active label alignment to top-left corner
Implemented VisaCustomOutlinedTextField class using MDCOutlinedTextField. In here i added trailing image
let visa_image = UIImage(named: "visa_img")

let visa_image_Button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    visa_image_Button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0),
                                      width: CGFloat(45), height: CGFloat(self.frame.height))
visa_image_Button.setImage(visa_image, for: .normal)

self.leadingView = visa_image_Button
self.leadingViewMode = .always

added label
self.cardNumberTextField.label.text = "Card Number"
but when touch inside it floating label not set to left top corner because of padding. need to set it proper way


